# Export Data from Hadoop using sql-spark-connector (Apache)

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to export data from Hadoop to MS SQL using Apache Spark SQL Connector as instructed here [sql-spark-connector](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector,) which fails with exception **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer (Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/ISQLServerBulkRecord;)V**

According to official documentation [Supported Versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npwU3.png)

**My Development Environment:**
Hadoop Version: 2.7.0
Spark Version: 2.4.5
Scala Version: 2.11.12
MS SQL Version: 2016

**My Code:**

```
package com.company.test

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object TestETL {   
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {  
    val spark:SparkSession = SparkSession  
      .builder()  
      .getOrCreate()  
    import spark.implicits._  
  
//  create DataFrame  
    val export_df = Seq(1,2,3).toDF("id")  
    export_df.show(5)  
  
//  Connection String  
    val server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://ip_address:port"  
    val database_name = "database"  
    val url = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"  
    export_df.write  
      .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark")  
      .mode("append")  
      .option("url", url)  
      .option("dbtable", "export_test")  
      .option("user", "username")  
      .option("password", "password")  
      .save()  
  }  
}
```

**My SBT**
[build.sbt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7kN0.png)

**Command line argument I executed**
/mapr/abc.company.com/user/dir/spark-2.4.5/bin/spark-submit --class com.company.test.TestETL /mapr/abc.company.com/user/dir/project/TestSparkSqlConnector.jar

[JDBC Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bew1f.png)

I de-compiled the mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre8.jar to check if it is missing the SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer method implementation but that doesn't see to be the case.

Any insights on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

it is a compatability error please to reffer to this link it will explain the error or just choose compatible versions. [gitHub link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark/issues/76)

Comment: The compatibility issue mentioned here is for the old connector https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark (old connector). I am trying to use sql-spark-connector (the new connector)

Comment: Yes exactly you have right but just try to change the versions with the same script.